# How to get laptop and desktop to always appear as the same machine?

Tags: backup, rsync, shared-folders, user-management, nas

I am setting up a desktop and laptop for someone. Both will be used by the same person for the same things. The person in question is not very skilled with computers.

The laptop has a mere 100gb of storage. The desktop will have several terabytes available.

My intent is that both machines have the same files at all times, so that the user never has to remember which machine a file was placed on, and never has to transfer files between machines. It should be as seamless as possible, ideally.

My initial idea was to set up rsync to run once an hour, but that will not copy over things like browser favourites and logins.

I also am aware that I could make the laptop a "light machine" that merely accesses a profile on the desktop, but I have used such a system before and it is quite slow.

The use will also need to take the laptop away sometimes, where it may or may not have internet access.

I intend to use ubuntu 18 LTS for both machines, but that's not fixed.

The user is unlikely to fill the 100gb on the laptop, but it would be nice if more could be stored on the desktop and the laptop merely act as a cache.

The desktop will be always on, though it will need to tolerate power outages and such.

Finally, I intend to use the desktop's large storage as a backup for another, separate, machine. However, that comes second.

How should I approach this setup?

Comment: "... that will not copy over things like browser favourites and logins." Why not? Why not copy the profiles of the apps across?

Comment: Avoid single-point-of-failure machines that have multiple purposes: If Uncle George unplugs his "desktop" to move it into the closet for the holidays, all your server containers and backups just went POOF! And if he did so while jobs were in process, the filesystem for all your backups just got corrupted.

Comment: For many light users, like Cousin Francis using e-mail and curating family photos, it's easy and convenient to use online services to host both application and data. It has the added benefit that you needn't be the only provider of support. Also, unless "someone" is a young child raised in a barrel, they likely *already have preferences*. Your setup must match their preferences, lest they promptly break it.

Comment: I don't really know how to respond to such comments. I have an old (if still overkill) desktop, and I have a bunch of old hard drives lying around with old photos and files from years ago. If I sell the desktop, then all the data on those old drives will sit in an attic gathering dust. If I set up both machines as independent machines (simple, and meets my second goal of using the desktop as a personal external backup, since I move around a lot myself), but I know it will cause frustrations when things get lost on one machine and the user will forget to check.